# Does ink on Sturgeon Shipyard's retractable bridges count in Turf Wars?

Tags: splatoon-3

Normally ink on walls doesn't count towards the final scores in a Turf War. However, Sturgeon Shipyard has two pairs of retractible bridges that raise and lower throughout a match. Do these retractible bridges count towards the final score?

[image: shipyard bridges being raised/lowered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ink on retractible bridges count. More specifically, only the "ground" of a bridge counts, regardless of whether the bridge has been raised or not.

[image: inking the top]

To test this I used recon to visit Sturgeon Shipyard in Turf War mode and carefully inked specific parts of the bridge to see how many points it gave me. After several attempts, I found inking the "ground" of a lowered bridge gave 34 points while the top of a raised bridge gave 0 points. I then inked the entire bridge to verify and once again got 34 points. The results were the same regardless of when the bridge was raised or lowered.

[image: inking the sides]

[image: inking the entire bridge]

Comment: I'd be surprised of the contrary, it's part of the map when closed, but nice discover for the top portion

Comment: @pinckerman I wasn't sure since one pair of bridges ends the round raised while the other pair ends the round lowered.